# Checking if a Broadcast Receiver is Working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, toast

I am working on an app that will use a BroadcastReceiver to pick up certain SMS messages that meet certain criteria. It's a long way short of finished, mainly because it seems that the BroadcastReceiver isn't working. I've tried to use a toast to check if it's working but I get no result. So either:

1. The BroadcastReceiver is not working
2. My method of testing is wrong
3. Or both

The AndroidManifest.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.alert6">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Alert6">

        <activity
            android:name=".SendResponseActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ReceiveAlertActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ReceiveAlertActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the SmsBroadcastReceiver java file

```
package com.example.alert6;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Is Being Received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
            String smsSender = "";
            String smsBody = "";
            for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                smsSender = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            }

            if (smsSender.equals("+420775367297")) {
                if (smsBody.contains("Test")) {
// I haven't done this bit yet
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I send a SMS to the test device I would expect a toast message saying "SMS Is Being Received". Instead the app disappears from the screen and my default SMS app appears instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add this permission in your manifest file?
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>`

Comment: @SergeyMelnik, yes, that's there. Perhaps I should have shown my full manifest file to make it clearer. I'll edit the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android API 23 you need set permission not only in manifest class, but also set permisson manually. You should set it in app's settings, or you should make permission reqeust from your code. This is what you need add in your main activity's file:

```
// constant for request code
private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE = 10; // any number which you want

//function for permission request
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void checkPermission() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE);
    }
}
```

Also you need call this function somewhere. For example you can make it in onCreate().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkPermission();
    }
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a permissions problem. I already have a bit of code similar to yours in the MainActivity file. The app also includes a page (Activity) to send SMS messages and that is working perfectly.

Comment: You could check is permission alllowed or not in you application's settings. If it allowed, it is really not a permission problem.

Comment: Good point @SergeyMelnik. I just had a look and the SMS permission is definitely there.

Comment: I created test [app](https://github.com/millerGrey/testSMS) for this question. I can't test it on real device right now, so I tested it on emulator only, and it works fine. You could compare it with your app and find a problem.

Comment: it works! To be honest, I didn't expect it to because my test phone is a Samsung Galaxy S8 using Android 9 and I was blaming either the Android version or something Samsung might have added. There are various apparently trivial differences between your code and mine, but I can't pinpoint the significant difference. I'm going to slowly build up my app again from zero, using your code as necessary. Huge thanks.

Comment: Was it permission problem?

Answer (score 0):

After a huge amount of fiddling and testing, I came to the conclusion that the broadcast receiver is not working. Probably due to Android's limitations on "dangerous" permissions. I don't think this thread has any life left in it, but I will continue to try to persuade my Android app to work with the necessary permissions.